# Running a Java programme on Debian

Tags: java, linux, terminal, debian

I am trying to move a programme I have from hosting it from a Windows machine to a debian one. I have installed JRE and JDK on the machine.

The .bat file I usually use is -

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe" -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -cp bin;lib/*     org.zarketh.Server false
pause
```

This is the command I try to use on terminal -

```
java -cp bin;lib/* org.zarketh.Server false 43594
```

I get the following error

```
lib/gson-2.2.2.jar: line 1: $'PK\003\004': command not found
lib/gson-2.2.2.jar: line 2: $'\227\220\342@': command not found
lib/gson-2.2.2.jar: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\332\001\001X5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The separator for classpath on *nix is `:`, not `;`, so:

```
java -cp bin:lib/* org.zarketh.Server false 43594
```

It's worth noting that this is also true of the `PATH` environment variable, which uses `:` on *nix and `;` on Windows.

---

The *reason* you're seeing the error you're seeing is that `;` in most (all?) shells (*nix command lines) is an *end of command* separator. So it was treating what you typed as two separate commands:

```
java -cp bin
lib/* org.zarketh.Server false 43594
```

I guess the `gson-2.2.2.jar` file has the executable bit set, so the shell was trying to run it (directly, not with Java)... :-)